# VGG16 same output prediction

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network, vgg-net

I have this VGG16:

```
def vgg16(trainImages, trainLabels, testImages, testLabels):
    trainImages = np.array(trainImages)
    trainLabels = np.array(trainLabels)
    testImages = np.array(testImages)
    testLabels = np.array(testLabels)
    
    trainImages = trainImages / 255
    testImages = testImages / 255
    
    model = Sequential()

    model.add(Conv2D(input_shape = (224, 224, 3), filters = 64, kernel_size = (3, 3), padding = "same", activation = "relu"))
    model.add(Conv2D(filters = 64, kernel_size = (3, 3), padding = "same", activation = "relu"))

    model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size = (2, 2), strides = (2, 2)))

    model.add(Conv2D(filters = 128, kernel_size = (3, 3), padding = "same", activation = "relu"))
    model.add(Conv2D(filters = 128, kernel_size = (3, 3), padding = "same", activation = "relu"))

    model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size = (2, 2), strides = (2, 2)))

    model.add(Conv2D(filters = 256, kernel_size = (3, 3), padding = "same", activation = "relu"))
    model.add(Conv2D(filters = 256, kernel_size = (3, 3), padding = "same", activation = "relu"))
    model.add(Conv2D(filters = 256, kernel_size = (3, 3), padding = "same", activation = "relu"))

    model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size = (2, 2), strides = (2, 2)))

    model.add(Conv2D(filters = 512, kernel_size = (3, 3), padding = "same", activation = "relu"))
    model.add(Conv2D(filters = 512, kernel_size = (3, 3), padding = "same", activation = "relu"))
    model.add(Conv2D(filters = 512, kernel_size = (3, 3), padding = "same", activation = "relu"))

    model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size = (2, 2), strides = (2, 2)))

    model.add(Conv2D(filters = 512, kernel_size = (3, 3), padding = "same", activation = "relu"))
    model.add(Conv2D(filters = 512, kernel_size = (3, 3), padding = "same", activation = "relu"))
    model.add(Conv2D(filters = 512, kernel_size = (3, 3), padding = "same", activation = "relu"))

    model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size = (2, 2), strides = (2, 2)))

    model.add(Flatten())

    model.add(Dense(units = 4096, activation = "relu"))

    model.add(Dense(units = 9, activation = 'softmax'))

    opt = Adam(learning_rate = 0.001)

    model.compile(optimizer = opt, loss = 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])

    model.fit(trainImages, trainLabels, epochs = 5)

    pred = model.predict(testImages)

    for i in range(len(pred)):
        print(np.argmax(pred[i], axis = -1))
```

I want to classify images in 9 classes. Input shape is (224, 224, 3). The problem is that I got the same prediction for all images, also training accuracy is very low, around 10%. I created another CNN and I got 97.8% accuracy for this dataset. What is the problem?

Comment: Did you try to upload VGG16 weights directly and fine tune the model? you can see here : https://keras.io/api/applications/vgg/
You might also try to add some regularization terms at the top of the model.

Comment: No, but I dont understand why is this big difference and why I get same outputs

Comment: The model is underfitting ( finding difficulties to learn on the images ), you can consider changing the model via the link I sent you.

Comment: Do you have a link with an implementation? Something more than that function?